# “The system printing service doesn't seem to be available” on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: printing, services

Printing was working yesterday but stopped for some unknown reason. The only thing I did was to alter some of the editable printer settings but now don't have the option to change them back.
I tried one answer already posted in this forum ("Printing service not available") but without success.

I then found Question, "system printing service not available ubuntu 18.10" and ran: systemctl status cups.service
which returned

```
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Fri 2019-05-10 12:53:47 BST; 35min ago
     Docs: man:cupsd(8)
  Process: 4222 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cupsd -l (code=killed, signal=TERM)
 Main PID: 4222 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

May 10 12:53:47 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: cups.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 10 12:53:47 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: cups.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 10 12:53:47 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
May 10 12:53:47 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: cups.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 10 12:53:47 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: cups.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
May 10 12:53:47 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.
```

I also tried this:

```
mike@mike-XPS-13-9370:~$ systemctl status cups.socket
● cups.socket - CUPS Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Fri 2019-05-10 12:29:05 BST; 2h 23min ago
   Listen: /run/cups/cups.sock (Stream)

May 10 12:29:05 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
May 10 12:29:05 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Closed CUPS Scheduler.
May 10 12:29:05 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler.
May 10 12:29:05 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: cups.socket: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 10 12:29:05 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: cups.socket: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
May 10 12:29:05 mike-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Failed to listen on CUPS Scheduler.
```

The computer is a Dell XPS, with Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8 processors; Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) Graphics; running Gnome 3.28.2 and is 64 bit. I am the only user but when I run a search for "cups", the file system only shows the .cups folder, which only has 1 file (lpoptions), in Home>Mike>.cups.

If I try the Troubleshooter, it tells me to look in Main>System>Admin>Services for the cups service but I can't find the Main menu, which I notice someone else has also had a problem finding!

I am a complete novice when it comes to Linux, so need leading gently by the hand. Thanks!

Comment: In your browser type http://localhost:631/ to access the CUPS service

Comment: Thanks, Graham, I tried that but it didn't work: "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect."

Comment: Does this link help? https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html.en

Comment: If I run, "sudo apt install cups", it returns "cups is already the newest version (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4)" How do I find "/var/log/cups/error_log"? I tried searching the Home directory but it found nothing.

Comment: from you home directory in terminal type cd /var/log/cups Another link for you: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems

Comment: Did that: mike@mike-XPS-13-9370:~$ cd /var/log/cups
mike@mike-XPS-13-9370:/var/log/cups$

Comment: If you made configuration changes and then the system stopped working, I would guess that those changes caused the problem.  Fortunately cups provides an original version of the config file for you. It's in /etc/cups and is called cups.conf.O  So my advice would be to copy your current config file to a backup: `sudo cp /etc/cups/cupsd.conf /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.backup` then copy the original over the one in use `sudo cp /etc/cups/cups.conf.O /etc/cups/cupsd.conf` then restart the service `sudo service restart cupsd`.  Disclaimer: I know little about cups but this is what I would try.

Comment: This will probably wipe out all printers you have set up, but I am not sure about that part.

Comment: Thanks, Organic Marble, but I only made printer changes via the dialog boxes, not via Terminal, so I don't quite understand how I killed printing! Nevertheless, I will try what you suggest, as I no longer have access to the two printers I have connected to the laptop.

Comment: Tried that, Organic Marble, but nothing seemed to happen with the backup and the second instruction returned: cp: cannot stat '/etc/cups/cups.conf.O': No such file or directory

Comment: Then: sudo service restart cupsd
restart: unrecognized service

Comment: Sorry, the service seems to be called cups, not cupsd.  Also I made a typo, it's cups*d*.conf.O, not cups.  You can list the files in the directory by typing `ls -l /etc/cups` Hopefully you get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve - copy the original config file over the one in use - and can overcome my mistakes :)

Comment: So the corrected version is: copy the original over the one in use `sudo cp /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.O /etc/cups/cupsd.conf` then restart the service `sudo service restart cups`

Comment: Tried all that but got this: restart: unrecognized service

Comment: ls -l /etc/cups
total 96
-rw------- 1 root lp     108 May  9 16:01 classes.conf
-rw------- 1 root lp     108 Nov 14 16:20 classes.conf.O
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26954 Apr  6  2018 cups-browsed.conf
-rw-r----- 1 root lp      22 May  9 16:07 cupsd.conf
-rw-r----- 1 root root    22 May 10 16:06 cupsd.conf.backup
-rw-r----- 1 root lp    4788 May  9 16:06 cupsd.conf.O
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2923 Apr  9  2018 cups-files.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr  9  2018 interfaces ...

Comment: ... drwxr-xr-x 2 root lp    4096 May  9 16:02 ppd
-rw------- 1 root lp     941 May  9 16:02 printers.conf
-rw------- 1 root lp     941 May  9 16:01 printers.conf.O
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   240 Jun  8  2018 raw.convs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   211 Jun  8  2018 raw.types
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   142 Apr  9  2018 snmp.conf
drwx------ 2 root lp    4096 Apr  9  2018 ssl
-rw-r----- 1 root lp    3301 May  9 16:07 subscriptions.conf
-rw-r----- 1 root lp    3160 May  9 16:06 subscriptions.conf.O

Comment: Joy, the printers have re-appeared in Settings-> Devices -> Printers, and work! I don't know how it happened, other than the last code I ran in Terminal, which did not work then. Maybe the laptop needed a good sleep?! Anyway, many thanks to Graham and Organic marble for your help.